# How to append loop values in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need append values different `div`-s

```
var thmb_count = thmb_wrap.length;

for( i = 0; i < thmb_count; i++){
    var num = i + 1; 
    thmb_wrap.each(function(){
        $(this).append('<span class="numeric">' + num + '/' + (full) + '</span>');
    });
}
```

html

```
<div class="thumb-wrp scrollbar-inner">
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/a.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/b.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/c.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/d.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/a.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/c.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/b.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/d.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where you want to append? on this `thm-img` class element?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what it is you want to do? It is hard to deduce it from the code you posted, that I suppose is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the `thm-img` and append the span's like

```js
var $thumbs = $('.thumb-wrp .thm-img'),
  full = $thumbs.length;
$thumbs.append(function(i) {
  return '<span class="numeric">' + (i + 1) + '/' + (full) + '</span>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-wrp scrollbar-inner">
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/a.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/b.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/c.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/d.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/a.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/c.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/b.jpg"></div>
  <div class="thm-img"><img src="img/img/d.jpg"></div>
</div>
```